# Ajax Request generates html with potential for subsequent Ajax requests. Secondary requests return [object mouseevent] as opposed to generated value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that is loaded via php.  One of the elements in the page is a `<li>` that has an onclick event.  E.g. `<li onclick="dynamiccall('1');">blah</li>`.  After clicking the element an ajax call is issued and the html output is inserted into the page, the tag looks as follows `<li onclick="getubilling('1');">blah</li>`.

After clicking the generated element with the onclick function getubilling('1');, an ajax call is sent to a php script.  The query parameter in the second function to getubilling is displayed as 1, but upon passing it to the ajax call, it shows up as [object mouseevent].  Why is this happening?

the dynamiccall() function is defined as follows in the ajax.js file included in the page:

```
function dynamiccall(uid){
    var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse10(xmlHttp.responseText);
          console.log(uid);
          var holder = uid;
          document.getElementById('orgcinfo').innerHTML = '<ul id="b_action_lst2"><li onclick="getuprofile('+holder+')" name="uprofile">Account Settings</li><li onclick="getubilling('+holder+')" name="billing">Billing</li><li onclick="getuchpass('+holder+')" name="chpass">Change Password</li><li onclick="getuadduser('+holder+')" name="adduser">Add User</li></ul>';

           var ullist = document.getElementById('b_action_lst2');
          var links = ullist.getElementsByTagName('li');

          for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
            var link = links[i];
            if(link.getAttribute('name')=="uprofile"){
                link.onclick = getuprofile;
            }
            if(link.getAttribute('name')=="chpass"){
                link.onclick = getuchpass;
            }
             if(link.getAttribute('name')=="billing"){
                link.onclick = getubilling;
            }
          }
          //dothis();
        }
      }
      xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?&p=anotherreq&uid="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    } 


function getubilling(uid){
var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse10(xmlHttp.responseText);
      console.log(uid);
      var holder = uid;
      document.getElementById('orgcinfo').innerHTML = '<ul id="b_action_lst2"><li onclick="getuprofile('+holder+')" name="uprofile">Account Settings</li><li onclick="getubilling('+holder+')" name="billing">Billing</li><li onclick="getuchpass('+holder+')" name="chpass">Change Password</li><li onclick="getuadduser('+holder+')" name="adduser">Add User</li></ul>';

       var ullist = document.getElementById('b_action_lst2');
      var links = ullist.getElementsByTagName('li');

      for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
        var link = links[i];
        if(link.getAttribute('name')=="uprofile"){
            link.onclick = getuprofile;
        }
        if(link.getAttribute('name')=="chpass"){
            link.onclick = getuchpass;
        }
         if(link.getAttribute('name')=="billing"){
            link.onclick = getubilling;
        }
      }
      //dothis();
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?&p=gubilling&uid="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

A request is issued to http://www.domain.com/ajax.php?&p=gubilling&uid=1&n=2212.32313

The problem is that the resulting UID variable when rendered in the browser results to [object mouseevent] as opposed to the literal value of 1.

I was following this [example](http://toddmotto.com/attaching-event-handlers-to-dynamically-created-javascript-elements/)  the only difference I can see is that the example doesn't provide for
          passing a dynamic element to the dynamicEvent function where mine does.

What am I missing?  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: A few questions: why are you using inline JS, and why aren't you using the `$.ajax` method available in jQuery since you have tagged the question as such?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this will be the default param passed into the onclick handler, the event object.

Why don't you use addEventListener for a start, rather than inline?

Answer (score 0):

How does this:

dynamiccall('uniqueid');

Know what uniqueid's value is? where does it get it from? In this case, it's taking the value of the event that occurred. My suggestion would be to change the tag to look like this:

```
<li onclick="dynamiccall(this);" uniqueid="1">blah</li>
```

then you can set dynamiccall to:

```
function getubilling(elem) {
    var uid = $(elem).attr('uniqueid');
...
```

Comment: the html, including the onclick=""  is generated on the server.  when I click the element dynamiccall('1');  and its function is executed and the onclick method gets appended to the list item.  When I attempt to execute the generated item with the onclick handler, it gives me [object mouseevent] as opposed to the original value of 1.

Comment: Basically I want to have one ajax request populate the document with html that contains another ajax request.  A variable in the second ajax request function contains the variable from the first ajax function.